# Rendering image using Mapnik and generate_image.py

Tags: python, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am trying to render image using Mapnik and generate_image.py script. Currently using very basic Mapnik style sheet. The highways are being drawn but there are extra lines coming from a single point. How can I get rid of these extra lines?

Screenshot of output image:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a different stylesheet?

Comment: yes tried different sheets and different map data source

Comment: And did they work any better?

Comment: changing the map data source changes the lines but the output is similar... I am unable to render a clear map output. Just about to try a different country map. Seen anything like this?